# CSS pseudo class of form input, disappeared in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

when i use an input with `required` and/or `pattern` attributes, the CSS pseudo class display on error. for example start typing some word (not digit) on this input and you see a red shadow around it:

```html
<input type=text pattern="\d+" required>
```

but when i use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and add `form-control` class to the input, the css pseudo class (red shadow) doesn't display on the input:

```
<input type=text pattern="\d+" required class="form-control">
```

how i can display the css pseudo class again?

Comment: Look at the css rules in the console of your browser. You will see what rule overrides your rule.

Comment: Have you set the style specifically yourself? Because bootstrap sets a border-color for input elements. The red border you're expecting is probably just your browsers internal stylesheet, and although bootstraps style selector is less specific, it still is rated more important. In other words: Try involving your own style for :invalid.

Answer (score 1):

I just commented this, but I'll also turn it into an answer because the appended snippet seems to work for me.

Have you set the style specifically yourself? Because bootstrap sets a border-color for input elements. The red border you're expecting is probably just your browsers internal stylesheet, and although bootstraps style selector is less specific, it still is rated more important.

In other words: Try involving your own style for :invalid and make it !important.

```html
<input type=text pattern="\d+" required>
<style> input:invalid { border:1px solid red !important; }</style>
```

```html
<input type=text pattern="\d+" required>
```

Comment: not border. a glow shadow. i use Firefox. i find that the problem return to **[this](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L2542)**, the `box-shadow` of bootstrap, override the box-shadow of Firefox for invalid inut. i solve the problem by adding `:-moz-ui-invalid{box-shadow:0 0 1.5px 1px red;}` to my css.